# How does one interpret the directory output from an rpm install/erase extra verbose command?

Tags: rpm

I have a problem where an rpm erase such as

`rpm -e <package>`

is causing a soft linked directory to be deleted. Whereas if the directory isn't a link but rather just a directory, it works fine.

To investigate this I started playing around with the extra verbose output -vv and it displays a lot of information, some of which is about the directories and files that are manipulated. However, I don't know how to read the output and I haven't been able to google any resources that explain the details.

An example of the output in question is as follows:

```
D:     erase: waitpid(4409) rc 4409 status 0 secs 1.107
D: fini      100755  1 (65534,65533)       105 /usr/foobar/tomcat/logs/om_be/dummy.log 
D: fini      040755  2 (65534,65533)      4096 /usr/foobar/tomcat/logs/om_be 
D: fini      100755  1 (65534,65533)       105 /usr/foobar/tomcat/logs/mc_be/dummy.log 
D: fini      040755  2 (65534,65533)      4096 /usr/foobar/tomcat/logs/mc_be 
D: fini      100755  1 (65534,65533)       105 /usr/foobar/tomcat/logs/dummy.log 
D: fini      120755  1 (65534,65533)        24 /usr/foobar/tomcat/logs 
D: fini      040755  2 (65534,65533)      4096 /usr/foobar/tomcat 
D: fini      100755  1 (   0,   1)      4293 /usr/foobar/share/mrtg2/icons/mrtg-ti.png 
[1]          [2]    [3]     [4]         [5]     [6]
```

[1] I suspect the `D:` is to indicate debug output. But what about `fini`? Does it have any significance?

[2] What about this group of digits (6 of them). They seem like they might be permission mode settings but there are too many numbers. At least the last three digits look like the octal mode values, I don't know what the first three would be.

[3] I have no idea what this column represents

[4] I'm guessing that the `(##,##)` portion is the owner and group permissions since they match the expected values for this.

[5] I have no idea what this number represents. Maybe size?

[6] I recognize the directory and file names. :)

Comment: So you want explanation for debug output or to solve why rpm -e <package> behaves differently with symlink and with a directory? If it's the latter, having at least partial *.spec file used to build the RPM would be extremely helpful. Just don't post it completely whole...tomcat spec is bound to be huge :-)

Comment: Hi Stan, more interested in the debug output. We've come to accept that it behaves this way because it's considered a file rather than directory, and long since worked around the problem. But I'm still interested in the debug output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug output comes from `lib/fsm.c` (function `fsmStage`). Relevant code snippet:

```
rpmlog(RPMLOG_DEBUG, " %8s %06o%3d (%4d,%4d)%10d %s %s\n",
            cur,
            (unsigned)st->st_mode, (int)st->st_nlink,
            (int)st->st_uid, (int)st->st_gid, (int)st->st_size,
            (fsm->path ? fsm->path : ""),
            _fafilter(fsm->action));
```

Where `cur` is string representation of current state of the action being performed (in your case action is erase and current state for subsequent tasks was **fini**shed succesfully). `st` is a standard `struct stat` so you have `mode`, number of `hardlinks`, `uid`, `gid`, `file/dir size`, `path`.

You guessed most of the debug items correctly. As for the mode not being just a simple 4 digit octal number, it's a bit more complex. From `stat` 2 manpage:
The following flags are defined for the st_mode field:

```
       S_IFMT     0170000   bit mask for the file type bit fields
       S_IFSOCK   0140000   socket
       S_IFLNK    0120000   symbolic link
       S_IFREG    0100000   regular file
       S_IFBLK    0060000   block device
       S_IFDIR    0040000   directory
       S_IFCHR    0020000   character device
       S_IFIFO    0010000   FIFO
       S_ISUID    0004000   set UID bit
       S_ISGID    0002000   set-group-ID bit (see below)
       S_ISVTX    0001000   sticky bit (see below)
       S_IRWXU    00700     mask for file owner permissions
       S_IRUSR    00400     owner has read permission
       S_IWUSR    00200     owner has write permission
       S_IXUSR    00100     owner has execute permission
       S_IRWXG    00070     mask for group permissions
       S_IRGRP    00040     group has read permission
       S_IWGRP    00020     group has write permission
       S_IXGRP    00010     group has execute permission
       S_IRWXO    00007     mask for permissions for others (not in group)
       S_IROTH    00004     others have read permission
       S_IWOTH    00002     others have write permission
       S_IXOTH    00001     others have execute permission
```